# Is it possible to use Capacitor plugins inside a macOS app built with Tauri?

Tags: angular, xcode, ionic-framework, rust, capacitor

I was recently introduced to Tauri and was trying to build a macOS distribution of my iOS app using Tauri. The iOS app is built using Angular v15, Ionic and Capacitor and it consumes several custom Capacitor plugins to make native calls for both iOS and Android. However, these plugins dont seem to work on the macOS distribution made with Tauri.

I have tried going through the Tauri [documentation](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/resources/) to embed external files and included the path to the build output of the plugins. But it did not help.

`tauri.conf.json`

```json
{
  ...
  bundle: {
    resources: [
      "../node_modules/@myplugin"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also could not find any resources on the topic. My question is if it is at all possible to use Capacitor plugins in this case? If so, any leads would be appreciated.